# Norm of $1-\omega$ where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

We are working in the number field $\mathbb Q[\omega]$, where $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}p}$, $p$ prime. This number field had degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb Q$ hence there are $p-1$ embeddings of $\mathbb Q[\omega]$ in $\mathbb C$. Such an embedding is a field homomorphism $\sigma_i:\mathbb Q[\omega]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ which fixes elements of $\mathbb Q$ and sends $\omega$ to one of its conjugates $\omega^{i}$, $i=1,\dots,p-1$. Hence the norm of $\mathbb Q[\omega]$ over $\mathbb Q$ is defined as $N(\alpha):=\sigma_1(\alpha)\cdots\sigma_{p-1}(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb Q[\omega]$.

Now we know that $(1-\omega)(1-\omega^{2})\cdots(1-\omega^{p-1})=p$. Then, being $1-\omega^{i}$ an algebraic integer, it's $N(1-\omega^{i})\in\mathbb Z$. Hence since
$
N(p)=p^{p-1}
$
and
$$
N((1-\omega)(1-\omega^{2})\cdots(1-\omega^{p-1}))=N(1-\omega)N(1-\omega^{2})\cdots N(1-\omega^{p-1})\;,
$$
$N(1-\omega^i)$ must be a power of $p$.

How can I show that $N(1-\omega^i)$ is *exactly* $p$ for every $i=1,\dots,p-1$?

If not, there exists $j$ such that $N(1-\omega^j)=1$ hence $1-\omega^j$ would be a unit in the ring of the algebraic integers of $\mathbb Q[\omega]$. How a contradiction can follow from this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$x^{p-1}+ \cdots + x^2+x+1 = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (x- \omega^j)$$
since its roots are $\omega, \omega^2, \dots, \omega^{p-1}$. Hence, substituting $x=1$ we get

$$p = 1^{p-1}+ \cdots + 1^2 + 1^1 + 1 = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (1- \omega^j) =
 \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} 1- \sigma_i(\omega) = \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} \sigma_i(1-\omega) = N(1-\omega)$$

Now call $\omega^j=\xi$. The automorphism $\sigma_i$ sends $\omega \mapsto \xi$. So you can substitute $\xi$ with $\omega$ in all of what is written above, and you get $N(1- \xi)=p$.

In fact  $\ \omega, \omega^2, \dots, \omega^{p-1}$ are all "algebraically indistinguishable" in your cyclotomic field, because they are conjugate, hence there is no meaningful difference between  $1-\omega$ and $1-\omega^j$. They must have the same norm.